# FireBase Android SignIn Demo Not working

Tags: android, google-signin, firebase-authentication

Has anyone used Firebase and Google sign in demo?

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android/pull/21

I have given it a try and it compiles just fine but when I press on the Google sign in button, and I select my profile, the callback that I get onActivityResult result.isSuccess as false

```
/* *************************************
*               GOOGLE                *
***************************************/

/* Load the Google login button */
mGoogleLoginButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.login_with_google);
mGoogleLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
        }
    });

/* Setup the Google API object to allow Google logins */
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

Start activity for result call back below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN) {
        /* This was a request by the Google API */
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String emailAddress = acct.getEmail();
            getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin(emailAddress);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, " Sign in Result is not success");
    }
}
```

Do I need to create a project for this on Googles Console API and the configuration file to this project in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue yesterday. The example seems to be outdated. I couldn't find a solution using the provided code. But there is a more intuitive way needing less code in the official documentation you can find [here.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)